# sqlite database can not be found in sqlite folder

Tags: java, sqlite, jframe, windowbuilder

I am creating an airline ticketing system on my mac and I made a SQLite database for random flight times to be shown on a Jtable after a button is clicked but when I go to the folder that the database is in it says that the database cannot be found when I clearly see it in the file.

and my table was made correctly

(here is my SQLite connection class)

```
    package travelling_Ticket;

    import java.sql.*;

    import javax.swing.*;

    public class sqliteConnection {
        Connection conn = null;
        public static Connection dbConnector(){

            try {
                Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
                Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:\\Users\\cjt1496\\sqlite\\flightTimes.db");
                return conn;
            }catch ( Exception e ) {
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
              }
              System.out.println("Opened database successfully");
              return null;
           }

        }
```

(Here is the button that is supposed to show the database table of the flight times inside of a Jtable and the error that shows after compiling is that the table flightTimes cannot be found)

```
    JButton btnLoadFlights = new JButton("Load Flight Times");
            btnLoadFlights.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                    try {
                        String query = "select * from flightTimes";
                        PreparedStatement pst = connection.prepareStatement(query);
                        ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();

                        table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));


                    }catch (Exception e1){
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            });
```

Comment: So, `"Opened database successfully"` is printed as it is expected?

Comment: yes it printed as expected @Geshode

Comment: If that message is displayed the database *didn't* get opened, though. You should change the message to one that's not misleading.

Comment: ok so  put a JOptionPane inside the "try" and it printed successfully

Comment: and deleted the other print